# Usage of "+" in array - php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to write a php script which redirects to different ".txt" documents by visiting the page "http://example.com/script.php" - for example my script for "http://example.com/script.php?data=ABC+DEF".
I got that far:

```
<?php
$targets = array("ABC+DEF" => "test.txt" /*, more redirects.. not the only one i have */ );

if (isset($_GET["data"]) && array_key_exists($_GET["data"], $targets)) {
header("Location: {$targets[$_GET["data"]]}");
exit;
?>
```

The issue is that it doesn't work if there is a + character in the array(""); but it works with a -.

That means "http://example.com/script.php?data=ABCDEF" would work

also "http://example.com/script.php?data=ABC-DEF" works.

Only http://example.com/script.php?data=ABC+DEF does not work.

Do I have to mark the + with a slahsh or '+' for it to work? 
I'm just braindamaged rightnow and not getting anywhere at this point. 
Probably easy to fix with two characters. 
Thanks for your help.

---

Edit: Yeah I was braindead, fixed it without even urlencode.
Since I don't want to change or encode the url somehow I just leave a blank space between ABC DEF instead of using the + so it looks like this now:

```
array("ABC DEF" => "test.txt");
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a slash in the URL, or use urlencode. Apache often treats a `+` as a space instead of a character.

Comment: `urlencode` ???

Comment: You should probably encode the URI component; e.g: from JS `encodeURIComponent('ABC+DEF')` which yields `"ABC%2BDEF"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the URL encoded character for the `+`, which is `%2B`, as without being encoded it is interpreted as a space by many web browsers

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you using [addslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.addslashes.php) function when generate url then [stripslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: How would this solve the problem? [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) exists for exactly this purpose.